# How to populate a database column with random numbers

Tags: sql-server, database, sql

How do I populate a int column, currently empty, with random numbers with no duplicates?

Comment: How many numbers? What range should the numbers be in? Which database engine?

Comment: Random numbers without duplicates aren't random numbers.

Comment: "Random numbers without duplicates aren't random numbers." That's not correct. You can perform random sampling without replacement. For example, this is how political polling is done, when done correctly.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds:  Care to put your definition of random up against mine in a cryptographic showdown with your identity on the line?

Comment: Sure. Search Google on "hypergeometric distribution". You can certainly create a random number generator, where you are sampling without replacement.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds:  Googled...good read but I still don't get it.  It's probably my failing, not yours.  Can you explain how sampling without replacement from a population of 10 will produce a cryptographically secure 10th message?  If you send messages using 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9 and Eve is able to deduce that, how is the 10th message supposed to be secure?  If I uniformly sample from 1 to 10 even if Eve knows my first 9 keys she can't deduce the 10th.

Comment: What does that have to do with the decon's question? He wants random numbers with no duplicates. Did you even read the question?

Comment: Uh, you're welcome? Did you read the question?

Comment: Random does not imply cryptographic security.  If you are sampling a number at random in the range [1, 10], it's not cryptographically secure regardless of how the number is chosen, because it will take at most 10 tries to guess it correctly.  Similarly, choosing 9 numbers with no duplicates is every bit as secure as choosing 1 number with no duplicates.  It's essentially the same operation.  But again, cryptographic security is not the issue.  Randomness is.  If the user wants a set of non-duplicating numbers, the shuffling of those numbers can still be random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could make the column a primary key to prevent duplicates, though that's kind of a hack. You can remove the key later.

```
---- Create the variables for the random number generation
DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT;
DECLARE @Index integer

---- This will create a random number between 1 and 999
SET @Lower = 1 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 999 ---- The highest random number
SET @Index = 0 --- A while loop counter

--- Loop from 0 to 10
WHILE @Index < 10
BEGIN
  SELECT 'loop counter = ', @index
  SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
  --Insert @Random here.
  SET @index = @index + 1
END
```

Comment: Nice one, although since the OP asked for 'no duplicates' you should probably use a IF NOT EXISTS somewhere...

Answer (score 9):

If this is an existing table to which you added a new INT column, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyIntColumn = CONVERT(int, RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 10000);
```

This will populate the empty column with random numbers between 1 and 10000.

Comment: I think the range would be between 0 and 9999, but this does work nicely. I wonder what it's doing though... without the `CHECKSUM(NEWID())` part you just get the same number forever. I guess you need to seed with different values to get different values?